# MongoDB designer for using into html5

Tags: html, mongodb, user-interface, yii2, code-hinting

first of all my english is the worst and that is shameful but i want to create a dashboard with yii2 that all users create their own no-sql data base (like mongo) in their dashboard

here is my question is there any extension for design mongodb that users can create their own db

i exactly looking for a mongodb designer that has a UI for using into html5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know the are no such specific modules for yii2, but you can tru integrate [default tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/) for manage mongodb.